# Typescript - property '0' is missing in type

Tags: typescript

I don't understand what this error means. I am trying to declare an Array that contains arrays of two numbers. For instance,

```
[[1, 2], [4, 3], [5, 6]]
```

These are the type signatures I'm using.

```
const knightTour = (start: number[], size: number): void => {
    const [i, j] = start;
    let path: number[][] = [];
    const queue: Array<[number[]]> = [start];
}
```

However, I'm getting the aforementioned error when I try to initialise my queue variable. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The complete error message is:

> ```
> (parameter) start: number[]
> Property '0' is missing in type 'number[]' but required in type '[number[]]'.(2741)
> ```

and it reveals where the error is.

```js
const queue: Array<[number[]]> = [start];
```

The type of `queue` is array of `[number[]]` (array of arrays of arrays of numbers)
and you want tot initialize it with an array of arrays of numbers.

I suspect the type of `queue` is incorrect and it should be `Array<number[]>`.

Comment: Isn't `Array<number[]>` the same as `number[][]`? @Perplexityy If so, maybe consider using the latter. Since `number[][]` is already used in another part of the function, maybe it would be easier for readers of the code to see the "array of array of number" type expressed in the same way inside the function, for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @axiac's answer:

The type:

```
[number[]]
```

is a [Tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) type which matches arrays of size one, whose only element has type of `number[]`.

So valid values for that type would be:

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[77, 33]]
[[]]
```

e.t.c. It is obvious that `[number[]]` is not a useful type. I would think that a tuple type makes sense if there are at least two elements in a tuple. For example this type:

```
[string, number, number[]]
```

could be used to store a string, a number and an array of numbers (if an application has a need for such a record).

```
['one', 1, [1]]
['six', 6, [1, 2, 3, 6]]
['ten', 10, [1, 2, 5, 10]]
```

In your case it's obvious that it's just a simple error. The intention seems to be that `queue` should be an array of arrays. So the type of `queue` can be just:

```
number[][]
```

and its definition and initialization:

```
const queue: number[][] = [start];
```

or just:

```
const queue = [start];
```

and let TypeScript infer the `number[][]` type.